# C# Using table.row.field values in a report header/footer

Tags: c#, reportviewer, header, field

now that my head is no longer swollen from pounding against the wall on untyped dataset report building, I have a new issue (head still hurts).

I have a dataset that has two result tables in it.  The first table has some summarization and other "static" values as a result of the query / processing to build the detail table for running the report.

How can I get the "Field" values from "Table1" into the report header.  When trying to do so, it chokes and says no fields allowed in header or footer of reports --- man, this is SO complicated in comparison to Visual FoxPro (VFP) reporting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry all, self-resolved...  I have to remove the same name parallels from my VFP development, they are not the same context.

```
VFP - Title page = appears once at beginning of report
VFP - Header = appear at top of each page
VFP - Detail = what appears for each row in report
VFP - Footer = appear at bottom of each page
VFP - Summary page = appears once at end of report

C# - Header = VFP Title Page
C# - Footer = VFP Summary Page

C# - Body = VFP Header, Detail and Footer all in one.
C# - Body - add a TABLE Control to do individual rows as needed
```

From the infamous Homer Simpson ---   Doooohhhhhh!!!!!